# NextJS initial state is not updating when routing to same page with different params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, url-routing, next.js

This project is using `NextJS`

I have a page which URL looks like this

```
localhost:3000/first/second
```

I call `getInitialProps` on that page. Data is passed from `getInitialProps` to the component as it should be and I am setting initial state with that data like this

```js
const Index = ({ data }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data.results)
}
```

Now when I send the user to

```
localhost:3000/first/third
```

`getInitialprops` is called as it should be. `data`, that is a parameter of component, is always populated with the latest results from `getInitialProps` but `state` isn't. It is populated with previous data that was in it. It is not resetting when I am doing client-side routing. Only when I hard refresh the page.

As suggested on `NextJS GitHub` I tired adding `data.key = data.id`, in ```getInitialProps``,` that is always a different number to force state update but it is not working.

Any info will be useful.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using NextJS, `getInitialProps` is called before the page renders only for the first time. On subsequent page renders (client side routing), NextJS executes it on the client, but this means that data is not available before page render.

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps):

> For the initial page load, getInitialProps will run on the server only. getInitialProps will then run on the client when navigating to a different route via the next/link component or by using next/router.

You would require a `useEffect` to sync state:

```
const Index = ({ data }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data.results);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data.results);
  }, [data]);
}
```

Comment: Well.. that was easy.. isn't it.. hahahaha.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I was banging my head thinking that nextjs should just render the components when the props get updated but it does and I had to use a direct href till I found this and it was the aha moment. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if it is the same with `getServerSideProps` function? If so, can you point it to the docs? I can't find anything. I'm having the same error and I fixed it with this solution.